# React Native + Firebase Cloud Messaging - Get Token Yields Service Worker Errors

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I've been trying to configure and set up Firebase Cloud Messaging on my React Native app, since I'd like my project to have peer to peer push notifications. I would like to publish this for Android, and eventually iOS, but I've been testing this in the web view (http://localhost:19006). This project is in TypeScript, and utilizes Stack.Router and Expo

./App.tsx

```
...
import FIREBASE from './src/http/firebase/interface';
...

export default function App() {
  
  React.useEffect(async () => {
    return await FIREBASE.init()
  });

  return (
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <GlobalContextProvider>
          <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
          <StatusBar />
        </GlobalContextProvider>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    );
}
```

./src/http/firebase

```
...
// EXPO INSTALL FIREBASE
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getMessaging, getToken } from 'firebase/messaging';

import { 
    FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    FIREBASE_WEB_VAPID_KEY,
    // @ts-ignore
} from '@env';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// @ts-ignore
let firebase;
// @ts-ignore
let messaging;
if (!firebase) {
  firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  console.log(firebase);
}

const init = async () => {
    // const registrations = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
    // if (registrations.length === 0) {
    //   const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js');
    //   console.log(registration)
    // }
    // @ts-ignore
    messaging = await getMessaging(firebase);
    console.log(messaging);

    switch(Platform.OS) {
      // case 'android':
      //   Do Nothing, as of now.

      case 'web': 
        // @ts-ignore
        if (messaging) {
          try {
            // @ts-ignore
            const token = await getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: FIREBASE_WEB_VAPID_KEY })
            if (token) {
              console.log(token);
            }
          } catch(err) {
            // TODO err handling
            console.log(err)
          }
        }
      // init app config
        break;

      case 'ios':
        break;
    }
};

const FIREBASE = {
    init,
    firebase,
    messaging,
};

export default FIREBASE;
```

Versions:

```
"react-native": "0.64.3",
"react-native-firebase": "5.6",
"firebase": "^9.6.11",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.8.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.8.0", // Multiple versions of Firebase packages since I was struggling, and followed a handful of different guides.
```

I've followed the guides to add common dependencies to ./android/build.gradle and ./android/app/build.gradle

The two logs for `firebase` and `messaging` yield a `FirebaseAppImpl` object and a `MessagingService` object as expected.
On loading the Web instance (`expo start` and select web) of the App, I am confronted with this error:

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:19006/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:19006/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
```

I *have* put a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in my root folder, and in my web-build folder, since I do not have access to a single /build folder.

When trying to load the app in an Android Emulator (Android Studio, Pixel XL API 30, Android 11.0 w/ Google APIs, otherwise default settings), I get the following errors:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener')]

[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).]
```

I'd appreciate any insight or help. I feel as if I've dug through hundreds of forum posts about Firebase and React Native at this point.

Comment: The app is in expo managed or in bare workflow?

Comment: @VickyAhuja this is a bare workflow, I've had to eject through expo.

Comment: If the project is in bare workflow then we should not initialise firebase app through js firebase library, instead we have to follow react native firebase documentation only. this will automatically initialise app with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

firebase messaging only support on **localhost** and **HTTPS** host

below is the snippet of my `@/plugin/firebase.js`

```js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getMessaging, onMessage, isSupported } from 'firebase/messaging'

const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
}

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

let messaging = null

isSupported().then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    const messaging = getMessaging(app)
    onMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
      const options = {
        body: payload.notification.body,
        icon: '/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png',
        click_action: payload.data.click_action || '/some/path/for/click/action',
      }

      navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration().then((reg) => {
        reg.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options)
      })
    })
  }
})

export default messaging
```

and `firebase-messaging-sw.js`

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-app-compat.js')
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.11/firebase-messaging-compat.js')


const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

let messaging = null

if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
  const messaging = firebase.messaging()
  messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload)
    const options = {
      body: payload.notification.body,
      icon: '/img/icons/android-chrome-192x192.png',
      click_action: payload.data.click_action || '/some/path/for/click/action',
    }

    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, options)
  })
}
```

hope those help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

React Native Expo Project,

add `web/` directory, place `firebase-messaging-sw.js` in it, and run `expo build:web` to have the firebase sw file properly referenced in the built index.html.